# firebase integration error: Google Play Services out of date

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to integrate Firebase in my android app. I'm using this [tutorial](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Cloud-Messaging). I updated my sdk manager, added `google-services.json` and did everything as mentioned in the website. Still I'm getting this `Google Play services out of date` error. I want to get the device token ID so that I can send it to server in Login Activity. Is there something else I need to do to get the device token ID?

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="MY_PACKAGE">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:label="@string/signin"/>
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:label="@string/cac"/>
        <service android:name=".services.RegistrationIntentService" android:exported="false"/>
        <service
            android:name=".services.FCMMessageHandler"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".services.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**app's build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "MY_PACKAGE"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**service**

```
public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {

    // abbreviated tag name
    private static final String TAG = "RegIntentService";
    public static final String SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER = "sentTokenToServer";
    public static final String FCM_TOKEN = "FCMToken";

    public RegistrationIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // Make a call to Instance API
        FirebaseInstanceId instanceID = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance();
        String senderId = getResources().getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        try {
            // request token that will be used by the server to send push notifications
            String token = instanceID.getToken();
            Log.d(TAG, "FCM Registration Token: " + token);
            System.out.println("Token:" + token);

            sharedPreferences.edit().putString(FCM_TOKEN, token).apply();
            // pass along this data
            sendRegistrationToServer(token);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
            // If an exception happens while fetching the new token or updating our registration data
            // on a third-party server, this ensures that we'll attempt the update at a later time.
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false).apply();
        }
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // send network request

        // if registration sent was successful, store a boolean that indicates whether the generated token has been sent to server
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true).apply();
    }
}
```

**logcat**

```
07-15 15:02:59.004 24479-24707/com.sam.bidnextjob I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
07-15 15:02:59.028 24479-24707/com.sam.bidnextjob W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 9256000 but found 9083234
07-15 15:02:59.029 24479-24479/com.sam.bidnextjob W/FA: Service connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}
07-15 15:03:59.033 24479-26561/com.sam.bidnextjob W/FA: Tasks have been queued for a long time
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a device side issue. Looking at your logcat:

> Google Play services out of date.  Requires 9256000 but found 9083234

Seems that your device is not running the required version of Google Play services. Try updating Google Play services on the the device and that should fix this issue.

Comment: As I mentioned to ~Al Zill, I updated Google Play services as well as repository before integrating firebase. The mobile device has Android 5.1 OS. I don't think I can update play services any more. Do I have to install the API 24 (Android N) library files too? @Arthur

Comment: I was talking about the version of Google Play services on the device. Check Settings > Apps > Google Play services and check the version.

Comment: Thanks Arthur for the clarification. I updated play services in mobile and got it resolved. But now the token should get generated. But I'm getting `FCM Registration Token: null` in LogCat. @Arthur

Answer (score 0):

Beside google play service, you also need to update google repository to the newest one. I don't know why there are no documentation about this either but update google repository solve my problem.